A1243: are left & right cmd physically distinguishable?
It turns out an apple keyboard A1243 is available at my work, but I'd need to remap both cmd keys to different keys (I plan to use keyd on linux), as the right/left alt are much easier to access this way with the thumb and are used a lot for instance to type french accents. But I tried to inspect the key events with xev, and it turns out that both left & right cmd keys have the same keycode (133).
So my question is: is it possible to actually differentiate these two keys (maybe at a lower level) or are they physically indistinguishable? I read that this keyboard can upgrade its firmware, maybe it can be a solution? Also, when I press shift + caps lock + tab, the TAB is never sent (instead another shift is sent), is this also a fundamental limitation of the keyboard? I'm asking because I use a lot this shortcut and it fails here.

What keyboard are you using at the moment? what other keyboards are available? Surely that can't be the only spare?

@SolarMike I ended up using a different keyboard, but I do like the the fact that the A1243 has a small key height (course), as I don't like when my fingers move too much when typing.
